# The text of the "Submit" button on Contact page is not localized

Tags: bug, status-completed, localization, contact

There is a link at the bottom of every SE page to the Contact page. And there's no transplantation of the word "Submit" on the button [on that page](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/contact):

> [image: untranslated submit]

Such button isn't translated on other international Stack Overflow sites:

- [Spanish SO](https://es.stackoverflow.com/contact)
- [Portuguese SO](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/contact)
- [Japanese SO](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/contact)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This issue is fixed now:

> [image: button translated]

But other related issues still exist:

- [Unable to translate sentence about chat room from Contact page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/366607/unable-to-translate-sentence-about-chat-room-from-contact-page)
- [Submit button is truncated on Contact page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/366456/submit-button-is-truncated-on-contact-page)