# Submit button is truncated on Contact page

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, contact

"Submit" button is truncated at the bottom of the [Contact page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/contact):

> [image: Submit]

Comment: Looks like that button sits in a `<div>` that is missing the 'grid' class. so `<div class="grid">` fixes it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Submit button is back in the `.grid--cell` where it belongs.

Thanks for the report!