# "mist" instead of "must", "inquery" instead of "inquiry" typos on Contact page validation error messages

Tags: bug, status-completed, error-message, spelling, contact

There two sentences with "mist" instead of "must" and "inquery" instead of "inquiry":

1. `The details of your inquery mist be at least $minLength$ characters.`
2. `The details of your inquery mist be at most $maxLength$ characters.`

Both strings can appear on the [Contact page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/contact/) under the "Please describe your problem" block at corresponding conditions after pressing "Submit" button.

[image: screenshot of error message with typo]

P.S. for the sake of ease of localization I suggest to add plural forms for each of these sentences.

Comment: This got nothing to do with localization or plurals. It's a bug in the spelling of the contact page error messages.

Comment: @ShadowWizardWearingMaskV2 spelling is the main issue, but since there is no plural forms (in terms of Transifex) for strings with a variable `$value$` - the second issue is pluralization for international SO sites.

Comment: You never mentioned Transifex, and the wrong text is shown on all sites. Anyway, doesn't matter that much, let's hope for a quick (?) fix.

Comment: Viry enteresting.

Comment: Is the submit button also clipped for you?

Comment: @Catija yes, good catch! Didn't notice it myself. But that's another bug...

Comment: @Catija [reported 2 weeks ago](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/366456/339911)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The typos have been corrected and the strings should support correct pluralization as well.

Thanks for the report!